How can we configure the shadowRoot related property while creating customElement(web-component) in angular
For ex. I want to set delgatesFocus property to true (default: false) which can be set using Element.attachShadow({mode:"open",delegatesFocus:true}). But I don't see any way to do this by using any angular customElement related API's. Can anyone help me out on this.
Couldn't find proper documentation/way in angular to achieve this.
